# PHP fputcsv with UTF-8 Problem

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, export-to-excel, fputcsv

I'm trying to allow my clients view some of the MySQL data in Excel. I have used PHP's fputcsv() function, like:

```
public function generate() {
   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ko_KR.UTF8');

   $this->filename = date("YmdHis");
   $create = $this->directory."Report".$this->filename.".csv";

   $f = fopen("$create","w") or die("can't open file");
   fwrite($f, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");

   $i = 1;
   $length = count($this->inputarray[0]);

   fwrite($f, $this->headers."\n");

   // print column titles
   foreach($this->inputarray[0] as $key=>$value) {
    $delimiter = ($i == $length) ? "\n\n" : ",";
    fwrite($f, $key.$delimiter);
    $i++;
   }

   // print actual rows
   foreach($this->inputarray as $row) {
    fputcsv($f, $row);
   }
   fclose($f);
  }
```

My clients are Korean, and a good chunk of the MySQL database contains values in utf8_unicode_ci. By using the above function, I successfully generated a CSV file with correctly encoded data that opens fine in Excel on my machine (Win7 in English), but when I opened the file in Excel on the client computer (Win7 in Korean), the characters were broken again. I tried taking the header (\xEF\xBB\xBF) out, and commenting out the setlocale, to no avail.

Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: can you try to add `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` at the top and tell me what would happen ???

Comment: Check out BOM (Byte Order Mask).  Which version of Excel are they using, 2003, 2007, etc?

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, your CSV file has *"correctly encoded data"* - i.e. that it contains a valid UTF-8 byte stream, and assuming that the byte stream of the file on your client's site is the same (e.g. has not been corrupted in transit by a file transfer problem) then it sounds like the issue Excel on the client's machine not correctly interpreting the UTF-8.  This might be because it's not supported or that some option needs to be selected when importing to indicate the encoding.  As such, you might try producing your file in a different encoding (using `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv`).

If you get your client to export a CSV containing Korean characters then you'll be able to take a look at that file and determine the encoding that is being produced.  You should then try using that encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the data as UTF-16LE, and ensure that the file has the appropriate BOM.

Alternatively, send your clients an Excel file rather than a CSV, then the encoding shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the text in each fwrite call with `utf8_encode`.

Then use what is suggested here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#69566

Comment: utf8_encode() [http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php] will only convert ISO-8859-1 (Latin1) into UTF-8.